# "ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function XYZ in region us-central1 in project ABC does not exist]"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, region

I am testing a cloud function.

When I run it from the "Testing" tab, online, and I paste the json dictionary as the argument to be passed as the request variable of the cloud function in the "Triggering event" editor as:

```
{"api_key":"MY_API_KEY"}
```

(with MY_API_KEY to be replaced with a plain text key) then the function runs through.

From bash, using `gcloud` instead, the same function fails with:

```
gcloud functions call MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION --data '{"api_key":"$API_KEY"}'
```

> ```sh
> gcloud functions call MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION --data '{"api_key":"$API_KEY"}' 
> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError:
> status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function MY_CLOUD_FUNCTION in region
> us-central1 in project MY_CLOUD_PROJECT does not exist]
> ```

And this is most likely not a problem of the triggering event which just happens to be part of the args but should not play a role here. It is a problem of the different regions. `gcloud` expects the default region `us-central1` while my function is `europe-west3` (from the "Details" tab).

How can I tell `gcloud` to use the region of the function, and not the default region? Or what would be another way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcloud` assumes defaults (that may be get|set using `gcloud config`)

In this case, you should add the flag `--region=europe-west3` to your command to specify the intended region, i.e.:

```sh
REGION="europe-west3"

gcloud functions call your-function \
--region=${REGION} \
--data="{\"api_key\":\"${API_KEY}\"}"
```

You can verify this behavior (hopefully) by:

```sh
gcloud config list
[core]
account = your@email.com

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

> **NOTE** The above command does not include `functions/region`; I suspect this is because `us-central1` is the default (!) default value.

```sh
gcloud config get-value functions/region
us-central1
```

I discourage storing global state in `gcloud config` (partly because it results in this type of confusion) but, you may also:

```sh
gcloud config set functions/region europe-west3
Updated property [functions/region].

gcloud config get-value functions/region
europe-west3

gcloud functions call your-function \
--data="{\"api_key\":\"${API_KEY}\"}"
```

Comment: works, also the default value is indeed `us-central1`. It seems I can also use `--data='{"api_key":"${API_KEY}"}'`, no need for the escaping backslashes. With or without the latter, I now get `ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[Permission denied on 'locations/europe-west-3' (or it may not exist)]' (or it may not exist)]` which is just a permission error and has nothing to do with the region error 404. Your answer still solves this. I will search for the 403 now :).

Comment: The region is `europe-west3` no second hyphen

Comment: Yes, if you wish to use bash expansion on the `--data` value you need to use my form. If you have string literals, use yours.

Comment: Ok, I took europe-west3 then, works.

Answer (score 2):

I have run to this problem in my experience trying to invoke a cloud function in GCP, specifying region did not solve it in my case, i kept getting same issue of "....does not exist".

I figured out that since am using Gen2 functions i needed to add the flag --gen2, so the final working commande was :

```
gcloud functions call functioned --region=europe-west1 --data='{}' --gen2
```